# AngularJS datetime comparison only takes time into account

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I have two datetime elements that I am trying to compare in AngularJS. The following code is functional, but only seems to take time into account:

```
    <td ng-style = "timenow > stop.time * 1000 && {'color': '#D8D8D8  '} || {}">
```

where `timenow = new Date()`, `stop.time` is UTC seconds (multiplied by 1000 because AngularJS uses miliseconds). I have tried a lot of different methods, such as `.toISOString()`, `.getTime()`, ... but it's always the same problem; the date part is not taken into account.

How do I get AngularJS to compare DATEtime, not just time?

Comment: `stop.time` is the number of seconds since when?

Comment: since January 1, 1970, midnight

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: I made a Plnkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/dQHqjkFJFHiWWB3mWQ6m?p=preview), which actually does work correctly with example data, so I started looking at the data from the API. Apparently there's a bug in the API which sometimes produces the correct time but the wrong date. In other words, my code was working, the data is was working with was faulty.